# How to find all tables having a specific foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.4

I have the table called `mailing` in the schema `mailing`:

```
id      name
PK    varcahr(32)
```

Is it possible to find all tables in all schemas having a foreign key to `mailing.id`?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a query i use to get the list of foreignkeys:
following query should help:

```
    SELECT RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FK_Name
    , KF.TABLE_SCHEMA FK_Schema
    , KF.TABLE_NAME FK_Table
    , KF.COLUMN_NAME FK_Column
    , RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME PK_Name
    , KP.TABLE_SCHEMA PK_Schema
    , KP.TABLE_NAME PK_Table
    , KP.COLUMN_NAME PK_Column
    , RC.MATCH_OPTION MatchOption
    , RC.UPDATE_RULE UpdateRule
    , RC.DELETE_RULE DeleteRule
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE KP.COLUMN_NAME='ID'
```

Comment: In spite of not working in the way you posted, your answer was very useful, thank you.